$L$ and $\epsilon$ factors for local Langlands correspondence
I am looking for an English reference for the construction of $L$ and $\epsilon$ factors in the local Langlands correspondence.
At the moment I am reading "The local Langlands correspondence for GL(n) over p-adic fields" by Torsten Wedhorn, but it is a list of definitions and propositions. It is not easy to work with it and look for something that is said in the text. So I am looking for another way. Is there anything clearer?

Bushnell and Henniart - The local Langlands conjecture for $\operatorname{GL}(2)$ is an accessible book, but, well, you can see from the title why it doesn't fully answer your question.

The articles "The local Langlands correspondence: the Archimedean case" by Knapp and "The local Langlands correspondence: the non-Archimedean case" by Kudla, both here, give a succinct description.
